# shipping a recompiled plugin under lgpl

Tags: python, licensing, plugins, lgpl

I have recompiled a plugin (making changes before they are accepted upstream) for the [gstreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/licensing.html) media framework.  I did not recompile the whole library -- just a plugin.

If I want proprietary python code to use this plugin -- am I running afoul of the LGPL license?  My code never *directly* links to the modified plugin.

MyPythonCode [proprietary] --> pygst/binary [LGPL] --> gStreamer/binary  [LGPL] --> modifiedPlugin/binary(w/source)[LGPL]

The source code for the modified plugin would be available per LGPL.

Answer (score 1):

If the original code is LGPL then your modifications to it are distributed under the LGPL and your code can use the LGPL plugin as a library - I don't see the problem?

The only issue would be if your proprietry code was a derived work of the LGPLed code - ie if you had used the library source as a basis for your code rather than just using the public API

Answer (score 0):

Your modified library can be used under the same terms as the LGPL'd library you modified.  This means that you have to release your modified version under the same terms and anyone can link their proprietary code to it, including you.